# QLabel не заполняется из другого класса

Tags: c++, qt

У меня приложение с картой, при нажатии на карту я рисую `Waypoint` и сохраняю его в мой `struct` `WaypointData`

Рисование `Waypoint` на карту

```
int MapViewClass::view_ObjectCallback(GlsMapView* self, DisplayEvent* ev)
{
    Vector lonlatalt;
    _pickedLocation.GetGeodetic(&lonlatalt);
    WaypointData* w = new WaypointData();
    w->iD = 0;
    w->state = 0;
    w->lng = lonlatalt.x;
    w->lat = lonlatalt.y;
    w->alt = lonlatalt.z;

    int iconType = 0;
    w->iconId = symbols->AddIcon(_pickedLocation,iconType);
    short nN = _dtedMapChartSource.GetElevationDataPoint(_pickedLocation);
    symbols->GetIcon(w->iconId)->SetResource("State", std::to_string(w->state).c_str());
    symbols->GetIcon(w->iconId)->SetResource("ID", std::to_string(w->iD).c_str());
    //Set Elevation Data
    symbols->GetIcon(w->iconId)->SetResource("NN", std::to_string(nN).c_str());
    //Set Height over Ground
    symbols->GetIcon(w->iconId)->SetResource("Height", std::to_string(w->alt).c_str());
    AddPathPoint(_pickedLocation);

    waypointData.push_back(*w);

    MainWindow *_MainWindor = new MainWindow();
   _MainWindor->PMission_BKS(w);
}
```

мой `struct`:

```
struct WaypointData    
{
    short iD;
    short iconId;
    double lng;
    double lat;
    double alt;
    int minAltitude;
    int state;    
};
```

Все это находится у меня в

```
namespace disti
{
    class MapViewClass : public ComponentBase
    {
    public:
```

В этой же фукнции где рисуется `Waypoint` вызывается функция из `MainWindow`

```
MainWindow *_MainWindor = new MainWindow();
_MainWindor->PMission_BKS(w);
```

Функция `PMission_BKS` находится в `public` в

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
```

Вот так выглядит моя функция `PMission_BKS`

```
void MainWindow::PMission_BKS(WaypointData* w)
{
    std::stringstream str;
    str << w->lng;
    ui->PMission_uberschrift->setText(str.str().c_str());
}
```

Проблема в следующем, если я пытаюсь вызвать `qDebug() << w->lng;` то получаю значение к примеру `10.5112`, если же пытаюсь вывести текст в `QLabel` или `QPlainText` то попросту ничего не вижу

Comment: зачем эти извращения с буфером и std::string? У вас уже есть готовые обёртки, не придумывайте свои костыли:  ui->PMission_uberschrift->setText(QString::number(w->lng));

Comment: ещё, рекомендую почитать про std::shared_ptr и std::unique_ptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По коду нельзя точно сказать, но есть предположение что проблема в этом месте:

```
MainWindow *_MainWindor = new MainWindow();
_MainWindor->PMission_BKS(w);
```

Приведите код где используется эта часть.

Есть подозрение, что Вы где-то одном месте создаете экземпляр MainWindow, который и отображаете на экране, а в вышепреведенном коде, вместо того чтоб использовать существующий MainWindow - создаете новый и для него вызываете PMission_BKS и там, в этом новом экземпляре даже корректно устанавливается значение QLabel, но эта форма не отображена на экране и Вы не видите измененией

Comment: Код приведен вот тут `Вот так выглядит моя функция PMission_BKS`. Вопрос тогда, как мне использовать части из `MainWindow` в `MapViewClass`, если `MapViewClass` уже объявлен в `MainWindow`? Т.е в `mainwindow.h` стоит `disti::MapViewClass *MapView;`

Comment: @Insider, у вас приведён код события, но нет кода, который это событие вызывает. Есть только создание экземпляра формы в куче и передача ей параметра, но, то что создано и используется в куче - не понятно. Приведите полный код. Это содержимое main функции?

Comment: @test123 подправил вопрос. PMission_BKS в main функции, остальное в MapViewClass

Comment: @Insider, >>вызывается функция из MainWindow<< значит Александр прав. Вы делаете какую то глупость. То что вызывается из MainWindow, не должно создавать нового MainWindow. Используйте this.

Comment: @test123 никогда не работал с this. Можно пример?

Comment: @Insider, XD умеете удивлять. this->PMission_BKS(w);

Comment: @test123 спасибо). Только вот откуда MapViewClass знает что в MainWindow есть PMission_BKS?

Comment: @Insider, вопрос не понятен. То что PMission_BKS находится внутри MainWindow говорит хотябы эта запись:  MainWindow::PMission_BKS(WaypointData* w). А что там у вас в коде - знают только экстрасенсы. Остальные могут рассуждать только на основании того что видят. Я вижу то что вы выложили, остальное могу либо придумать/додумать, либо не знать. По существу больше ответить нечего...

Comment: @test123 все что есть в коде, написано тут. А вопрос я задал примям текстом. Откуда int MapViewClass::view_ObjectCallback(GlsMapView* self, DisplayEvent* ev) узнает что есть PMission_BKS в MainWindow. Я не прописывал ничего связаного с MainWindow в классе MapViewClass, ибо попросту не могу, не позволяет. Поэтому пытался с MainWindow *_MainWindor = new MainWindow;

Comment: @Insider, если MapViewClass ничего не известно о текущем экземпляре формы - то это ваша проблема. Передавайте ему ссылку на форму, которая запущена.

Comment: @test123 В этом как бы и заключался вопрос. Я ведь сказал, что не могу передать ссылку на форму MainWindow ибо MainWindow уже знает о MapViewClass и компилятор выдает ошибку